# I'm trying to source values for a select drop down from a table using JavaScript and jQuery, but the select menu doesn't show any values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sql, drop-down-menu

This is the html for the drop down:

```
<div id="selectEvent" style="width:200px;">
    <select>
          <option value="0">Select Event:</option>
          <option value="1">Event Name</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

This is how I am trying to get the values from a table into the drop down list:

```
var options = [];

function callback(tx, results) {
    var htmlCode;
    var cmbType = $("#cboAddEventType");

    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) 
    {
        var row = results.rows.item(i);
        htmlCode += '<option value="' + row.id + '">' + row.name + '</option>';
    }

    cmbType.append(htmlCode);
    cmbType.html(htmlCode).val(1).change();
}

EventType.selectAll(options, callback);

var sqlInsertEventType = ["INSERT INTO eventType (name) VALUES ('Business')",
            "INSERT INTO eventType (name) VALUES ('Personal')",
            "INSERT INTO eventType (name) VALUES ('Commercial')"];
```

But nothing appears in the drop down when I run the application. It's empty. What's wrong? Does it matter what order I link the scripts in the html page or something?

Comment: You're using also PHP right?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an html element with id `cboAddEventType`, you should add this as an id for your select element.

```
<select id="cboAddEventType">
```

your code needs some more fixes, but I guess you will get them yourself.